# Python Pandas: How to only str.lower() Rows or Cells that contain a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

at the moment I am setting my whole "name" column to lowercase with this line.

```
df["name"] = df["name"].str.lower()
```

My problem is however, that I only want to str.lower() the cells that do not contain the string "Foo" in them.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
df["name"] = df["name"](lambda x: str(x) if "Foo" in str(x) else str.lower(x))
```

> TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension also works as below:

```
df['name'] = [str.lower(x) if x != 'Foo' else x for x in df['name']]
```

I've timed the other methods on a list of 300 names (of which 100 are Foo) 1000 times each and roughly timed it (I know there are better timing methods, but I used time.time() between for loops).  These are the timings in secconds below that I found for these methods:

```
list-comprehension : 0.049
.apply : 0.179
np.where : 0.349
.loc : 0.880
```

It may be that some of these methods would perform better on much bigger data sets than 300, so I understand that this is not a vigorous test. Others may be able to better say.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution missing [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df["name"] = df["name"].apply(lambda x: str(x) if "Foo" in str(x) else str.lower(x))
```

Or use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and apply lowercase only for filtered rows with `~` for test `NOT` match mask:

```
m = df["name"].str.contains('Foo')
df.loc[~m, "name"] = df.loc[~m, "name"].str.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[~ df['name'].str.contains('Foo'), 'name'] = 
    df.loc[~ df['name'].str.contains('Foo'), 'name'].str.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function can also work here, as below:

```
import numpy as np
df['name'] = np.where(df['name'].str.contains('Foo'),df['name'],df['name'].str.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[~df["name"].str.contains("Foo")]['name'].str.lower()
```

The term `df[~df["name"].str.contains("Foo")]` will return the DataFrame without `Foo` in column `name`. After that, we lower the column `name` by the remain term.